# Cannot generate proper RSA keys using openssl genpkey utility with RSA-PSS option

Tags: openssl

I am trying to create an RSA key using openssl on Linux and then converting it to PuTTY format so that I can use it from my Windows PC as well.

`openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA-PSS -out myKey.pem -outform PEM -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048`

Key is generated. I `cat` it, looks ok.

Now convert it to PuTTY format:

`puttygen myKey.pem -o myKey.ppk -O private`

I get following error:

`puttygen: error loading 'myKey.pem': unrecognised key type`

I tried to check the key using the following command:

`openssl rsa -in myKey.pem -text`

I get following error:

`140527068488128:error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA:expecting an rsa key:../crypto/evp/p_lib.c:464:`

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong algorithm: RSA-PSS instead of RSA.

This command would generate the intended key:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out myKey.pem -outform PEM -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

Note that the only change is replacing `RSA-PSS` with `RSA`.

---

For a given private key, you can retrieve informations about it, including the algorithm used, like this:

```
openssl asn1parse -in myKey.pem
```

the wrong algorithm (for SSH usage) would have a line similar to this among others:

```
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsassaPss
```

while the RSA algorithm will have something similar to this among others:

```
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
```

Comment: I didn't understand why is RSA-PSS wrong? It is supported and mentioned in the man page of `genpkey`, which states ... "Valid built-in algorithm names for private key generation are RSA, RSA-PSS, EC, X25519, X448, ED25519 and ED448"

Comment: you generate an RSA-PSS key then complain it doesn't decode as RSA with the last command. SSH (not openssl) doesn't support RSA-PSS. If you want to use SSH, you have a limited subset of valid key algorithms. RSA-PSS is not part of them, RSA is. Others are possible. ED25519 would be valid for openssh, I don't know for putty.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Maybe I should change the question title ... why the RSA-PSS keys cannot be used as normal RSA keys are used with SSH? AFAIK the RSA-PSS is just recommended PKCS#1 standard way to use RSA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme